# loading big xml file

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection

i'm trying to load big file from server, but when it's loading always very slow.
Can you suggest me method, how to fast load more, then 200k objects ?

```
Printing description of data:
(NSData *) data = 0x08e51d80 151341098 bytes

NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error,%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Show slow is "slow"?  150MB will always take some time, depending on the network being used.

Comment: @Droppy I'm not sure what you are asking. Please can you make your question to the OP more clear.

Comment: @Popeye I am trying to clarify the question.  How slow is the data being downloaded (i.e. bytes per second) and what would the OP expect?

Comment: @Droppy That wasn't really clear from your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points:

1. You can use file output stream for network request instead of holding the whole `NSData` in memory. For example, AFNetworking supports such option.
2. You can use a SAX parser with stream support for deserialising your data from file, to, again, avoid loading whole XML into memory. For example, `NSXMLParser` does support stream parsing.

Here's the example of setting up `NSXMLParser`:

```
NSInputStream *fileStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithURL:temporaryXMLFileURL];
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithStream:fileStream];
parser.delegate = yourParserDelegate;
BOOL result = [parser parse];
```

You can implement your parsing & object instantiation code in a class adopting `NSXMLParserDelegate`, there're a lot of examples over the internet, even [one](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000186i) from Apple.

Please keep in mind that all this tricks won't speed up *downloading* of your large file from the internet, it depends entirely on your connection speed. My approach would only help to reduce your application memory footprint (hence reducing the risk of your app being jettisoned by iOS because of memory pressure).

Comment: can you give example with nsxmlparser ?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to JSON.  JSON will load and parse MUCH faster than XML.  I have a JSON file that is 1.8 MB and it downloads and parses (I use AFNetworking for the connection) in around 7 seconds.  Another tip, cache the resulting NSArray on the device so that the next time, you can load directly from that cached array and in the background request the file again and compare to the cached Array.  If different, update the model with the new data.

Something like this:

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSError *error = nil;
            id jsonObj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error,%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

Comment: thanks for tips, but file xml and i cannot do something with that

Comment: You have no control over how the file is formatted?

Comment: depending on the xml format and what you are doing XML is MUCH faster than JSON. So no general asumption which works better for him.

Comment: I have never experienced XML parsing being faster than JSON on iOS.